# Dismiss 2 UIViewController that was loaded via a presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

When the user clicks on a button I am displaying a `UIViewController` as follows:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newviews"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, when the `vc` viewcontroller loads successfully, the user will click on another button and another `UIViewcontroller` is displayed. Again this too uses a `presentViewController:` as in the previous code.

Now, there's 2 `UIViewController` that's being displayed by `presentViewController:`,

When the user clicks on a button I need these 2 ViewControllers to Dismiss. How can I do this ?

I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES]` since you presented them modally. You can take advantage of the `parentViewController` property when dismissing viewControllers.

```
UIViewController *mainController = [UIViewController new];
UIViewController *vcA = [UIViewController new];
UIViewController *vcB = [UIViewController new];

// User taps button to present vcA
[mainController presentViewController:vcA animated:YES completion:nil];

// User taps button to present vcB
[vcA presentViewController:vcB animated:YES completion:nil];

// Dismiss both vcB and vcA
[vcB.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [vcA.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // Now you are back on mainController
    }];
}];
```